# Upload using axios and patch method doesnt work

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, axios, form-data

I am using Laravel 5.8 and Vue.js 2, this is my .vue file:

```
let data = new FormData();                           
data.append('name', this.name);
data.append('image',this.image)
data.append('_method', 'PATCH');
axios.patch('/url/' + this.id, data)                        
                     .then(({data}) => {                

                    })
                     .catch((error) => {

                    });
```

**Route**

```php
Route::patch('/url/{id}', 'CarsController@update');
```

**Error**

> Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'name' cannot be null.

But when I change the method to POST, both in my vue file and web.php it works, what is happening? I need to use both methods: post for new data and patch for updating. What can I do?

Comment: show your controller

Comment: it's `axios.post` with `_method: 'patch'`. `axios.patch` it not supported.

Comment: Have you tried switching to `put` both (client/server)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Http `patch` method does not support `FormData`. So either submit JSON request or change your route method to `post`. Also, if `patch` method is must have then you can submit `axios.post` with additional attribute `_method: 'patch'` which then can handle `FormData` request.

Comment: How can we submit JSON request?